# Minimal ROS2 runtime environment

Tags: linux, ros2

I'm researching about ROS2 so I can use it in my work, one thing I'm trying to do is to setup the runtime environment for an embedded Debian system. My plan is that I will write C++ code on my development machine, cross compile it to produce the binaries targeting my embedded system, package them as a `.deb` file, and install it on my embedded system.

I was thinking that I can specify the `ros-galactic-ros-base` package as one `.deb` file's dependencies. However, I notice that the `ros-galactic-ros-base` package pulls in a lot of dependencies that I think will not need for my runtime environment. For example, development packages (I'm guessing from the names) such as `ros-galactic-ament-cmake-gmock`, or `ros-galactic-ament-lint-auto` are not needed in the runtime environment.

Is there a package which specifies only the packages needed for the runtime environment?

Comment: that is already the small set missing a lot. The only other way is installing from the sources thought

Answer (score 0):

Just found about the connection of yocto and ros.

have a look [here](https://github.com/ros/meta-ros) it should do exactly what you want.

the learning curve is a bit steel thought